# Yii2 getting error Area must be string when selecting a text from dropdown

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `yii2`.

I have a below field in my `_form`

```
$form->field($model, 'area_name')
    ->widget(Select2::className(),[
            'data' => \common\models\AllowArea::toAreaArrayList(),
            'options' => ['placeholder'=>'Select Area'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ],
    ]);
        
?>
```

When I am trying to select from it I am getting

**Area Name must be a string.**

**GUI**

[image]

Below is my validation rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['user_id','created_by','updated_by'], 'integer'],
        [['area_name','user_id','salesman_code','city_name'], 'required'],
        [['area_code', 'user_name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['created_at'],'safe'],
        [['area_name', 'salesman_code', 'salesman_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

**Function**

```
public static function toAreaArrayList()
{
    $sds = Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("Select * from Area")->queryAll();
   
    return ArrayHelper::map(Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("select distinct AreaNameFull from Area where AreaCode NOT IN ('020201001','020202001')")->queryAll(),'AreaNameFull',function($sds, $defaultValue){
        return $sds['AreaNameFull'];
    });
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed `area_name` from `[['area_name', 'salesman_code', 'salesman_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],` to `[[ 'salesman_code', 'salesman_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],` and it's start working.

Answer (score 0):

Select 2 widget initializes in multiple mode. That means that the result is an array.

If it's not desired behavior, just remove `'multiple' => true`.

Otherwise, the field rule of the form should be

```php
['area_name', 'each', 'rule' => ['string', 'max' => 100]],
```